# not able to load data and DUMP in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
climate = LOAD '/home/MOCK_DATA.csv' USING PigStorage(','); 
DUMP climate;
```

I am getting this error.

> 2016-09-17 15:44:03,880 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the
>   script: UNKNOWN 2016-09-17 15:44:03,910 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use
>   dfs.bytes-per-checksum 2016-09-17 15:44:03,910 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2016-09-17 15:44:03,910 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple]
>   was not set... will not generate code. 2016-09-17 15:44:03,911 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer -
>   {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator,
>   GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter,
>   MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer,
>   PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter,
>   SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]} 2016-09-17 15:44:03,911 [main]
>   INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler
>   - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false 2016-09-17 15:44:03,913 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size before optimization: 1 2016-09-17 15:44:03,913 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size after optimization: 1 2016-09-17 15:44:03,926 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use
>   dfs.bytes-per-checksum 2016-09-17 15:44:03,927 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2016-09-17 15:44:03,928 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM
>   Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
>   2016-09-17 15:44:03,929 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script
>   settings are added to the job 2016-09-17 15:44:03,929 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3 2016-09-17 15:44:03,932 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Setting up single store job 2016-09-17 15:44:03,940 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission. 2016-09-17 15:44:03,949 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot
>   initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= -
>   already initialized 2016-09-17 15:44:03,950 [JobControl] ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl - Error while
>   trying to run jobs. java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found
>   interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was
>   expected  at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
>   2016-09-17 15:44:03,952 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 0% complete 2016-09-17 15:44:03,955 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure. 2016-09-17 15:44:03,955 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job null has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs 2016-09-17 15:44:03,955 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete 2016-09-17 15:44:03,958 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce
>   job(s) failed! 2016-09-17 15:44:03,958 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script
>   Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
>   2.6.0 0.16.0  hadoop  2016-09-17 15:44:03 2016-09-17 15:44:03 UNKNOWN
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   N/A   climate MAP_ONLY    Message: Unexpected System Error Occured:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
>     file:/tmp/temp-927714196/tmp-434253511,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from "/home/MOCK_DATA.csv"
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in
>   "file:/tmp/temp-927714196/tmp-434253511"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: null
>
> 2016-09-17 15:44:03,962 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed! 2016-09-17 15:44:03,963 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator
>   for alias climate Details at logfile:
>   /home/hadoop/pig_1474106148648.log

Comment: sem like permission issue or the path doesn't exist. the log message is pretty informative  `Input(s): Failed to read data from "/home/MOCK_DATA.csv"`

Comment: It could be that the data is not available, if that is not the case, please present the contents of  `/home/hadoop/pig_1474106148648.log`

Comment: check for the file path , the file may not exist in the location you provided.